# Login issue in Ubuntu

Tags: server, login, screen, system, ps

I can log in to the VPS server with an IP address but once log in to Ubuntu after some time its screen is locked then if I am trying to enter with the same password. It does not log in at all to the Ubuntu system. I entered the correct password also. I have attached a screenshot. Can you please help me?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The problem only with the **root** user?

Anyway check logs for any errors or warnings that occur around the time you unlock the screen and copy the errors into your Question with [Edit]:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

```
journalctl
```